# Bootstrap container or fill height 100% browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, height

I need to set the height container to 100% browser, but when you put the contents of the tags will break containter.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.container {        
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  background-color:red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> 
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080 " alt="" />
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080 " alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `vh` for full height. `100vh` = `100%`.
Now, use `container-fluid`for get full width on bootstrap 3